# VBA formula too long, ways to shorten it

Tags: vba, excel

Goodafternoon all,

Currently facing a VBA issue, where the "record macro" function does work, but when I try to rerun it, it gives me the 1004 error.
I recall that I could do three things:

1. Split the formula up in parts, then refer to the next part in the formula (ie part 2= abc+def+ghi, so formula is 123+3456+ ____, then replace ____ with part 2)
2. Put the formula as text in different cells, then refer to those cells in the formula (formula is cell("a1").value(?) + cell("b2").value(?)
3. Give parts of the code a specific name, so that it will shorten the formula (ie abc = 'INPUT - MOTC!' then refer to abc in the formula

Especially part 2 is something I could use some help with, since I don't know the exact reference, and I can always look back at the formula in the excel instead of going to the VBA.

The formula itself is:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(WEEKDAY(RC2)=6,COUNTIFS('INPUT - MOTC'!C90,""confirmed"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C101,""1"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C74,""500"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C86,""<>C"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C47,""<""&R2C11,'INPUT - MOTC'!C45,""<""&R2C12,'INPUT - MOTC'!C93,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C105,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C99,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C47,RC2)" & _
    "+COUNTIFS('INPUT - MOTC'!C90,""confirmed"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C101,""1"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C74,""500"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C86,""<>C"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C47,""<""&R2C11,'INPUT - MOTC'!C45,""<""&R2C12,'INPUT - MOTC'!C93,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C105,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C99,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C47,RC2+1)" & _
    "+COUNTIFS('INPUT - MOTC'!C90,""confirmed"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C101,""1"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C74,""500"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C86,""<>C"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C47,""<""&R2C11,'INPUT - MOTC'!C45,""<""&R2C12,'INPUT - MOTC'!C93,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C105,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C99,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C47,RC2+2)" & _
    ",COUNTIFS('INPUT - MOTC'!C90,""confirmed"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C101,""1"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C74,""500"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C86,""<>C"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C47,""<""&R2C11,'INPUT - MOTC'!C45,""<""&R2C12,'INPUT - MOTC'!C93,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C105,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C99,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C47,RC2)"
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is the formula just too long?

(little background, I would like to add the values of saturday&sunday to the value of friday, so if weekday is 6, then do so).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why did you mix both R1C1 style and common style in your formula?

Comment: To put formula into cell using VBA, You should use only R1C1 style

Comment: What do you exactly mean by R1C1 style? And where am I not using it? Sorry, relatively new to this subject.

Comment: R1C1 is row column style e.g. in your formula above you use RC2. A1 style is the excel current formula style e.g you use C90 in your formula. The R1C1 style of C90 would be R90C3

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation. C90 here actually refers to column 90, 'INPUT -MOTC'!$CL:$CL, so am I still adhering to the R1C1 rule?

Comment: Yes you are - `C90` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shorten the formula like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(WEEKDAY(RC2)=6,SUM(COUNTIFS('INPUT - MOTC'!C90,""confirmed"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C101,""1"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C74,""500"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C86,""<>C"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C47,""<""&R2C11,'INPUT - MOTC'!C45,""<""&R2C12,'INPUT - MOTC'!C93,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C105,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C99,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C47,RC2+{0,1,2}))" & _
    ",COUNTIFS('INPUT - MOTC'!C90,""confirmed"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C101,""1"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C74,""500"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C86,""<>C"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C47,""<""&R2C11,'INPUT - MOTC'!C45,""<""&R2C12,'INPUT - MOTC'!C93,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C105,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C99,""No"",'INPUT - MOTC'!C47,RC2))"
```

Comment: The formula is still too long for any human to digest and understand the intent of the calculation.

Comment: Absolute nonsense. Any halfway competent excel user should be able to understand that. (Length is not the same as complexity). I'll overlook the implication that I am inhuman.

Comment: This is `VBA` generated, so there shouldn't be any repeating hard coded strings. What if something got moved or renamed? This is hell for the next poor soul who is responsible for this. I am certain it is going to show up on thedailywtf.com as some point.

Comment: Since you don't know what else the code is doing, or any of the circumstances, you can't reasonably make an assertion like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rory, unfortunately I still get the 1004 error message. Will check out the code and then come back to you if that's ok?

Comment: I've just edited the code - it was missing a closing bracket at the end of the formula.

Comment: Works like a charm!!!! Thanks a lot Rory.

Is it correct that my formula was just too long and therefore gave me the 1004 error?

Comment: No - the macro recorder is at fault. When it tries to break up long formulas into multiple lines, it ends up replacing parts of the actual formula with the additional characters needed for the line breaks, so the formulas are no longer correct.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.
For future reference: The "RC2+{0,1,2}" part loops the formula 3 times, correct? So date (which is what the RC is reflecting), date+1, date+2.

Thanks a lot again for helping me out! I owe you at least one beer :)

Comment: Correct - it effectively creates an array of COUNTIFS formulas, and that array is then totalled by the added SUM function.

Answer (score 2):

This formula is completely unmaintainable. Never do this again!

I personally never use VBA to set formulas in cells. I always do the calculation in VBA and only present the results in cells. This has the disadvantage of not being a "live" calculation and requiring a trigger (like a button press) but is makes it easier to maintain.

I suggest move all your calculations in VBA.

- Individual input cells need to be named ranges

[image: name]

- Pull the values into VBA with `x = Range("OrderDate").Value2`
- If you have a table than you know the size you can pull the values into a VBA array.

For example with a 100×7 table:

```
Dim table_values() as Variant
table_values = Range("top_left_cell").Resize(100,7).Value2
' to loop through values
For i=1 to 100
    table_values(i,7) = ...
Next i
' Replace the values with new calculated values
Range("top_left_cell").Resize(100,7).Value2 = table_values
```

- Keep you complex calculations split up in steps *with comments*

For example:

```
Set r = Range("table_name")
For i = 1 To n
    'Find the column with the date
    d = r.Offset(i - 1, 2).Value2
    If WorksheetFunction.Weekday(d) Then
        ' If weekday count items with ...
        n_confirmed = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( '...
        n_shipped = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( '...
    Else
        ' otherwise count  ...
        n_confirmed = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( '...
        n_queue = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( '...
    End If
    ' Fill the result
    r.Offset(i - 1, 3).Value2 = n_confirmed + n_shipped + n_queue
Next i
```